# Python np.select match some conditions to multiple choices

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
id variable value
1    x        5
1    y        5
2    x        7
2    y        7
```

Now I want to rename some of the variables to something else and for the rest of the variables, I want to map them to two different variables(rest of the row will be copied as it is). For example, in the above dataframe I want to rename `x` to `x1` and `y` to `a` and `b`. I am looking for something like this:

```
conditions = [(df['variable']=='x'),(df['variable']=='y')]
choices = ['x1',['y1','y2']]
df['variable'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='NA')
```

So final dataframe will be like:

```
id variable value
1    x1       5
1    a        5
1    b        5
2    x1       7
2    a        7
2    b        7
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to change the shape of the data , you can try this approach which joins the list with a delimiter then we can explode the column and join:

```
conditions = [(df['variable']=='x'),(df['variable']=='y')]

s=pd.Series(np.select(conditions,['x1','|'.join(['a','b'])])).str.split('|').explode()

out = df.join(s.rename("variable_new"))
```

---

```
print(out)

   id variable  value variable_new
0   1        x      5           x1
1   1        y      5            a
1   1        y      5            b
2   2        x      7           x1
3   2        y      7            a
3   2        y      7            b
```

EDIT for pandas versions lower than 0.25:

```
conditions = [(df['variable']=='x'),(df['variable']=='y')]

df['variable'] = (pd.Series(np.select(conditions,
                 ['x1','|'.join(['a','b'])])).str.split('|'))
out = (df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['variable'].str.len())]
       .assign(variable=np.concatenate(df['variable'])))

print(out)

   id variable  value
0   1       x1      5
1   1        a      5
1   1        b      5
2   2       x1      7
3   2        a      7
3   2        b      7
```